# store state of value to avoid multiple calls and not pass as parameter

Tags: java, spring, state

In my spring mvc application, Trying to refactor the code to avoid multiple calls to a method.

```
@RestController
Class A{

@Autowired
Service1 service1

@Autowired
Service2 service2

@RequestMapping(value = "/****/***", method = RequestMethod.GET)
aMethod(){

    service1.service1Method(a,b)

    service2.service2Method1(a,b)

    service2.service2Method2(a,b)

}

@Component
class Service1{

    service1Method(a,b)
    {
        String someValue = util.utilMethod();
    }

}
@Component
class Service2{

    service2Method1(a,b)
    {
        String someValue = util.utilMethod();
    }

    service2Method2(a,b)
    {
        String someValue = util.utilMethod();
    }
}
@Component
class Util
{
    String utilMethod()
    {
        return "something"
    }
}
```

The `utilMethod()` calls three time, to get a value.Here trying to avoid the multiple calls and can handle by one.

I can call utill method in controller and pass the value as a third parameter.Like this.

```
@Autowired
Service1 service1

@Autowired
Service2 service2

@Request
aMethod(){

    String someValue = util.utilMethod();

    service1.service1Method(a,b,someValue)

    service2.service2Method1(a,b,someValue)

    service2.service2Method2(a,b,someValue)

}
```

But don't want to do like this.because lot of code changes are required.
Is there any way I can store the value in (but not request, session) controller and can get service1 and service2 classes.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is the better way to do it.By adding member variable(setter/getter) in service class.But Hope should be better way can handle by Spring

```
@RestController
Class A{

@Autowired
Service1 service1

@Autowired
Service2 service2

@RequestMapping(value = "/****/***", method = RequestMethod.GET)
aMethod(){

    String utilValue = util.utilMethod();
    service1.setUtilValue(utilValue);

    service1.service1Method(a,b)

    service2.service2Method1(a,b)

    service2.service2Method2(a,b)

}

    @Component
    class Service1{

    String utilValue;//setter and getter

    service1Method(a,b)
    {
        //String someValue = util.utilMethod();
       String someValue = this.getUtilValue();
    }
```